# Docker compose not exposing port for application container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have exposed port 80 in my application container's dockerfile.yml as well as mapping "80:80" in my docker-compose.yml but I only get a "Connection refused" after I do a "docker-compose up" and try to do a HTTP GET on port 80 on my docker-machine's IP address. My docker hub provided RethinkDB instance's admin panel gets mapped just fine through that same dockerfile.yml ("EXPOSE 8080") and docker-compose.yml (ports "8080:8080") and when I start the application on my local development machine port 80 gets exposed as expected.

What could be going wrong here? I would be very grateful for a quick insight from anyone with more docker experience!

Comment: can we see your dockerfile and docker-compose

Comment: Yes , the contents of the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, `docker-machine env` as well as some command output would help answer this question.  It's possible that maybe the application isn't  binding to port 80?  You can make sure the config is correct using `docker inspect`, and make sure the app is running as you expect with `docker logs` or `docker-compose logs`

Answer (score 4):

So in my case, my service containers both bound to localhost (127.0.0.1) and therefore seemingly the exposed ports were never picked up via my docker-compose port mapping. I configured my services to bind to 0.0.0.0 respectively and now they works flawlessly. Thank you @creack for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Getting my services to listen on 0.0.0.0 worked as well. Thanks for this.

Comment: this helped me as well

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using

```
docker-compose run app
```

Apparently

> docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

I started using

```
docker-compose create app
docker-compose start app
```

and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that the service I am trying to set up had all their networks as `internal: true`.  It is strange that it didn't give me an issue when doing a `docker stack deploy`

I have opened up https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6534 to ask for a proper error message so it will be obvious for other people.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the same Dockerfile, make sure you also expose the port 80 `EXPOSE 80` otherwise, your compose mapping `80:80` will not work.
Also make sure that your http server listens on `0.0.0.0:80` and not localhost or a different port.

Comment: I don't think this is true. You don't need to `EXPOSE` if you use ports.